# Derivation of a curve that is not directly expressed

Tags: calculus, derivatives, curves

I have read the question below and I couldn't figure out what it was asking:

> Curve $C(x,y)$ is defined as below. Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ expressed in $a$.
> $$x=a-\sin(a)~, \quad y=1-\cos(a)$$

The problem of mine with that question is that I cannot rewrite the curve equation linking $y$ directly to $x$.

Every answer is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  $\dfrac{\operatorname dy}{\operatorname dx}=\dfrac {\frac{\operatorname dy}{\operatorname da}}{\frac{\operatorname dx}{\operatorname da}}$.  (This is Leibniz's suggestive notation.)

Answer (score 1):

Quantity which is to be find $\cfrac{dy}{dx}$, 
$$ \cfrac{dy}{dx} = \cfrac{dy/da}{dx/da} = \cfrac{\sin(a)}{1 - \cos(a)} $$

Comment: Thank you! But I still can't imagine the curve. What is "a" denoting here. I might be stuck in much horrid trouble if I am asked to calculate the surface of the area bounded by curve and x-axis. Then, I can't do anything since every formula I know works by x and y - not a third parameter which connects them.

Comment: t is parameter, and the curve is cycloid, see this https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/acdexa6p

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Parametric Equation of Cycloid is $$x=a-\sin(a)~, \quad y=1-\cos(a)$$
Now from the above equation $$\cos(a)=1-y$$$$\implies\sin(a)=\sqrt{1-(1-y)^2}$$$$\implies\sin(a)=\sqrt{2y-y^2}$$
$$\implies a=\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2y-y^2}\right)$$

So $$x=a-\sin(a)\implies x=\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2y-y^2}\right)~-~\sqrt{2y-y^2}$$
$$\implies x~+~\sqrt{2y-y^2}=\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2y-y^2}\right)$$

This is the relation between $~x~$ and $~y~$.

---

Here
$$x=a-\sin(a)~, \quad y=1-\cos(a)$$
Now
$$\frac{dx}{da}=1-\cos(a)\qquad \text{and}\quad \frac{dy}{da}=\sin(a)$$
$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{da}}{\frac{dx}{da}}=\frac{\sin(a)}{1-\cos(a)}$$

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle parametrization all the way ( both differentiation and integration)
$$ y^{'}=\cfrac{dy}{dx} = \cfrac{dy/da}{dx/da} = \cfrac{\sin(a)}{1 - \cos(a)} =\tan(a/2)$$

$$  A= 2 \pi \int _{a1} ^{a2} y\sqrt{1+y^{'2}} dx =2\pi \int _{a1} ^{a2} y\sqrt{1+y^{'2}} \frac{dx}{da} da $$
$$=2\pi \int _{a1} ^{a2} (1-\cos \alpha) .\sec(a/2). (1-\cos \alpha). da $$

Can you express $a/2$ argument trig function in the middle in terms of $a$ and take the integration from there?